# Display single feature from a vector layer in OpenLayers

Tags: openlayers

given a feature ID I want to hide all other features on a vector layer and only display that one feature on my map. is this possible?

Answer (score 2):

never mind I fixed it, it was easier than I thought...

> sprintersLayer.features[labId].style = { fillColor: "green"};
>       map.layers[1].redraw();

I simply changed the styling of the specific feature I wanted.

Comment: can you eloborate map.layers[1].redraw(); it gives error

Comment: note that this answer is from 2012. I am sure the library has changed since then, and I haven't used it since then...

Comment: Great! I recommend you add the solution as an answer to help the next person

Answer (score 0):

to hide all other features on a vector layer and only display that one feature of id=labId on your map ,you can use this code

```
for(var f=0;f<sprintersLayer.features.length;f++) {
 if(sprintersLayer.features[f].id !="labId")
  {
  sprintersLayer.features[f].style = { visibility: 'hidden' };}

  }
```

it works in my project tell me if it works or not ,good luck .